# Determine external dependancies for Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Sometimes when installing a new gem to my system, I get an error:

`Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

I know this is most often caused by an external library not being installed on the system.

An example of this would be `fileutils` which has `rmagick` as a dependency. But `rmagick` will not compile until you have installed `imagemagick`, `libmagickcore-dev`, and `libmagickwand-dev`, which are not ruby gems and so will not be exposed with `gem dependency`.

So, is there a good way to determine beforehand what external libraries a ruby gem depends on?

Comment: There should be some text which described exactly _how_ the build failed, should be useful...

Comment: Yes, there is, and I can fairly easily track down what the external library is, and it is a piece of cake to fix, but I am trying to automate this whole process for incoming devs and for the setup of new virtual environments. Quite frankly, it should manage itself...

Comment: If there is any information, then that should be written in the rakefile of the gem.

Answer (score 0):

There's no formal declaration for what dependencies a gem has, and it's not even possible to describe them since the package name will vary wildly from one OS to another, or even from one distribution to another. It'd be nice if there was more feedback here. [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/) does a great job of interpreting errors and suggesting fixes, but this is way more than most do.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I'm pretty sure that's for checking the contents of the gem itself, not external dependencies.